# How to distinguish keys in created filetable

Tags: sql-server

I follow an online example of how to create a file table with script like this

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] AS FILETABLE ON [PRIMARY] FILESTREAM_ON [FGFS]
    GO
```

And when I run the query like

```
SELECT * FROM sys.key_constraints WHERE parent_object_id=xxxxx
SELECT * FROM sys.index_columns WHERE object_id=yyyyy
```

The first one gives me 3 keys (1PK+2UQs)

How can I learn which one is 
either `FILETABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT_NAME` or `FILETABLE_STREAMID_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME` or `FILETABLE_FULLPATH_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any table, you can quickly get the index details with `sp_help`:

```
EXEC sp_help N'dbo.Users';
```

The index details will be like:

```
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
|         index_name          |                  index_description                   |        index_keys         |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| PK__Users__5A5B77D52FBBA93E | nonclustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY | path_locator              |
| UQ__Users__9DD95BAF3C1BB377 | nonclustered, unique, unique key located on PRIMARY  | stream_id                 |
| UQ__Users__A236CBB35BE6FD63 | nonclustered, unique, unique key located on PRIMARY  | parent_path_locator, name |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
```

The query below will return the constraint name and column name(s) using the catalog views:

```
SELECT kc.name AS constraint_name, c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.filetables AS t
JOIN sys.key_constraints AS kc ON kc.parent_object_id = t.object_id
JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic ON ic.object_id = kc.parent_object_id AND ic.index_id = kc.unique_index_id
JOIN sys.columns AS c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE t.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Users', 'U')
ORDER BY kc.name, ic.key_ordinal;
```

Comment: Thank you, is `exec` the only way to know its detail?

Comment: @TheUnknown, there are several different methods. I added an example using the catalog views to my answer.